# Simulate a 12-sided fair die with a 10-sided fair die

Tags: probability-theory, dice

> If I have a single 10-sided fair die and I want to simulate a 12-sided fair die, what would be the most efficient way to do so?

Thus, we have to ensure that the likelihood of each result is equally likely.

Comment: My totally unsubstantiated guess: Toss it repeatedly until it is not showing 10. Mark the result modulo 3. Toss it repeatedly again, until it is not showing either 9 or 10. Mark the result modulo 4. Combine the two results using the Chinese Remainder theorem.

Answer (score 7):

One of the first ideas that could come to mind is to roll the $10$-sided fair die twice. Substract $1$ to each result, you get two random integers from $0$ to $9$. Consider these as the digits of a single integer $n$ between $0$ and $99$. If $n\geqslant96$, start all over again. If $n\leqslant95$, divide $n$ by $12$, keep the rest, add $1$ to it. You are now contemplating a result of a $12$-sided fair die.

In this procedure, one starts all over again in $4$ cases from $100$ and each round uses two rolls of the $10$-sided fair die, thus, to get each (simulated) result of the $12$-sided fair die, one needs a mean number of $$\frac2{1-\frac4{100}}=\color{brown}{\bf 2.083}$$ rolls of the (real) $10$-sided fair die.

But one can do significantly better...

Roll the $10$-sided fair die $\color{red}{\bf 109}$ times. Substract $1$ to each result, you get $\color{red}{\bf 109}$ random integers from $0$ to $9$. Consider these $\color{red}{\bf 109}$ integers as the digits of a single integer $n$ between $0$ and $10^{\color{red}{\bf 109}}-1$. The base-$12$ expansion of $n$ is a number with at most $102$ base-$12$ "digits". If the leading base-$12$ "digit" is $1$, start all over again. Otherwise, the leading base-$12$ "digit" is $0$, that is, $n$ is a number with at most $\color{green}{\bf 101}$ base-$12$ "digits". Add $1$ to each of these $\color{green}{\bf 101}$ base-$12$ "digits". You are now contemplating $\color{green}{\bf 101}$ results of a $12$-sided fair die.

In this procedure, the chances to start all over again are 
$$1-\frac{12^{\color{green}{\bf 101}}}{10^{\color{red}{\bf 109}}}=0.62\%$$ (but see note 3 below), thus, to get a large number $N$ of (simulated) results of the $12$-sided fair die, one needs roughly $$\frac{\color{red}{\bf 109}}{\color{green}{\bf 101}}\cdot\frac{10^{\color{red}{\bf 109}}}{12^{\color{green}{\bf 101}}}=\color{purple}{\bf 1.086}$$ times $N$ rolls of the (real) $10$-sided fair die.

**Note 1:** Yes, the trick is that $12^{\color{green}{\bf 101}}=9.938\cdot10^{108}$ is only marginally smaller than $10^{\color{red}{\bf 109}}$, and the idea is simply to pick a power of $10$ very close to, and larger than, a power of $12$, to minimize the number of times one must start all over again.

**Note 2:** No, this procedure is not optimal since one could pick some higher power of $12$ smaller than, and even closer to, some higher power of $10$, and proceed likewise. This remark shows that there can be no optimal procedure because, for every $p<1$, there exists some integers $m$ and $n$ such that $$p\cdot10^n\leqslant12^m<10^n$$ (this is a standard consequence of the ergodicity of irrational rotations of the unit circle), thus, the procedure based on $n$ rolls of the $10$-sided fair die yields a new result of the $12$-sided fair die roughly every $$r=\frac{n}{p\cdot m}$$ rolls of the $10$-sided fair die. If $p$ is close to $1$ and if $n$ and $m$ are very large, then $$r\approx\frac{\ln(12)}{\ln(10)}=\color{blue}{\bf1.079}$$ which is thus the theoretical optimal efficiency one can approach but never reach.

**Note 3:** One could try to reach an even higher efficiency of the $\color{red}{\bf 109}$-throws-for-$\color{green}{\bf 101}$-results procedure described above, re-using the rounds producing a base-$12$ number with leading "digit" $1$ since each of these rounds produces a number uniformly distributed on $6.18\cdot10^{106}$ values. Decomposing these values into $10$ stacks of size $12^{98}=5.75\cdot10^{105}$, one could generate $98$ results of a $12$-sided fair die when falling in one of these stacks, and start all over again otherwise. But the gain in the mean number of (simulated) results of the $12$-sided fair die per result of the $10$-sided fair die is negligible.

Comment: I am upvoting this one, as this is the only answer addressing the question of optimality. There is an ambiguity in the question, though: If the problem is just to optimally simulate a *single* roll of the 12-sided die, you are way off the mark. But for an infinite or very large number of rolls, spot on! With the caveat that, if you are going to use it for a game, you need a trusted third party to do the rolling and to reveal the simulated rolls one by one to the players.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen See addition to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let the faces be labelled $0,\ldots,9$. Repeatedly roll the die $m$ times to form a decimal $\alpha=0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_m$ and say that the outcome is $\lfloor 12\alpha\rfloor$.
The challenge is to make $m$ as small as possible. To do so, stop as soon as $\alpha\le x<\alpha+10^{-m}$ implies $\lfloor 12x\rfloor =\lfloor 12\alpha\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

You could simulate a 12-sided die by rolling multiple times. Since $12 = 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$, you could do the following:

1. Throw a first time, result $r_1$ modulo 2. Throw a second time, result $r_2$ modulo 2. Throw a third time until you don't hit a 10, result $r_3$ modulo 3. Then set the result $r = 6 r_1 + 3 r_2 + r_3 + 1$. The expected number of rolls equals $2 + \frac{10}{9} \approx 3.11$.
2. Throw a first time until you don't hit a 7, 8, 9 or 10, result $r_1$ modulo 6. Throw a second time, result $r_2$ modulo 2. Then set the result $r = 2 r_1 + r_2 + 1$. The expected number of rolls equals $\frac{10}{6} + 1 \approx 2.67$.
3. Throw a first time until you don't hit a 9 or 10, result $r_1$ modulo 4. Throw a second time until you don't hit a 10, result $r_2$ modulo 3. Then set the result $r = 3 r_1 + r_2 + 1$. The expected number of rolls equals $\frac{10}{8} + \frac{10}{9} \approx 2.36$.